# Google Compute Engine + Cloud SQL + Cloud DNS + Google Domains - IP Changed

Tags: php, nginx, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dns

I've been running a successful Wordpress install on Google Compute Engine with LEMP (Linux, NGINX, MySQL and PHP) stack, and Cloud SQL (Generation 2 MYSQL) and tried to tie in the domain last night using Cloud DNS.

I added the A record and CNAME and adjusted the nameservers in Google Domains, but nothing is loading.

At first, I was getting a 504 Bad Gateway NGINX/Ubuntu error, but now nothing happens.

However, I noticed that my IP address for Compute Engine changed, not sure how probably misunderstood something that I was reading and said yes.

Is there a way to change the Cloud SQL to see the new IP address? If so what is the process?

Trying to avoid having to rebuild everything, but I guess that's how you learn what not to do in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Every Google Compute virtual machine has assigned by default an ephemeral IP address, which gets changed every time you restart it. You can [read more about IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses), however I recommend you just [promote](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#promote_ephemeral_ip) the current ephemeral address as a static one and update your Wordpress config settings.

Please keep in mind that you could be in a [security risk](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine#gce-connect-ip) at this moment, because the old IP address that you granted access to your database might be assigned to another user.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the IP's, but how do you actually change the WordPress config settings when you can't get into your WordPress site through the VM.

Comment: It should be possible to SSH into the VM, even though it changed it's IP address. You can go to the [instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) page, find your VM and click the `SSH` URL under `Connect`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex Palcuie's great answer re promoting a VM's ephemeral IP to a static IP, [here's how you reconfigure Cloud SQL to allow only the new IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip).